# Trouble selecting functional proxies from a list of proxies quickly

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests, proxy

I've created a scraper using requests module implementing rotation of proxies (taken from a free proxy site) within it to fetch content from yellowpages.

The script appears to work correctly but it is terribly slow as it takes a lot of time to find a working proxy. I've tried to reuse the same working proxy (when found) until it is dead and for that I had to declare `proxies` and `proxy_url` as `global`.

Although `shop_name` and `categories` are available in landing pages, I scraped both of them from inner pages so that the script can demonstrate that it uses the same working proxy (when it finds one) multiple times.

This is the script I'm trying with:

```
import random
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

base = 'https://www.yellowpages.com{}'
link = 'https://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=pizza&geo_location_terms=Los+Angeles%2C+CA'

headers = {
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/102.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
}

def get_proxies():   
    response = requests.get('https://www.sslproxies.org/')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,"lxml")
    proxies = []
    for item in soup.select("table.table tbody tr"):
        if not item.select_one("td"):break
        ip = item.select_one("td").text
        port = item.select_one("td:nth-of-type(2)").text
        proxies.append(f"{ip}:{port}")

    return [{'https': f'http://{x}'} for x in proxies]


def fetch_resp(link,headers):
    global proxies, proxy_url

    while True:
        print("currently being used:",proxy_url)
        
        try:
            res = requests.get(link, headers=headers, proxies=proxy_url, timeout=10)
            print("status code",res.status_code)
            assert res.status_code == 200
            return res
        except Exception as e:
            proxy_url = proxies.pop(random.randrange(len(proxies)))


def fetch_links(link,headers):
    res = fetch_resp(link,headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
    for item in soup.select(".v-card > .info a.business-name"):
        yield base.format(item.get("href"))


def get_content(link,headers):
    res = fetch_resp(link,headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
    shop_name = soup.select_one(".sales-info > h1.business-name").get_text(strip=True)
    categories = ' '.join([i.text for i in soup.select(".categories > a")])
    return shop_name,categories


if __name__ == '__main__':
    proxies = get_proxies()
    proxy_url = proxies.pop(random.randrange(len(proxies)))
    for inner_link in fetch_links(link,headers):
        print(get_content(inner_link,headers))
```

***How can I quickly select a functional proxy from a list of proxies?***

Comment: I updated my answer with another working example for your use case.  Let me know how this new example works for you.

Comment: What are your speed requirements for selecting a working proxy? What are your speed requirements for scraping the webpages?

Comment: Quicker than the way it is already doing the job. There are no fixed and definitive rules about the speed by the way.

Comment: Python can't do this quickly. You need something Async.

Comment: @pguardiario what do you mean by async?  I’m asking this because the free proxy list continually changes and a large percentage of them fail the sniff test out of the gate.  I get less than 20% working in all my testing.

Comment: Async means it doesn't wait for a response. There's Asynchio / Twisted for Python but I don't know if there's a async requests lib that does proxies

Comment: @pguardiario so the connects fails when it doesn’t produce results? If so, how is that much faster then checking if the proxy is working prior to using?

Comment: Because you have to wait until it fails before you can try another one. You want to be able to test all of them at the same time.

Comment: Even after testing the proxies and getting a valid response code of 200 they can still fail, which is why I added all the error code in my answer.  I just tried using `Asynchio` and it was not as fast as using the threading model I put in my answer.  In that answer I can check 100 proxies in 40 seconds or less.

Answer (score 1):

*Please let me point out that using free proxy IP addresses can be highly problematic. These type of proxies are notorious for having connections issues, such as timeouts related to latency. Plus these sites can also be intermittent, which means that they can go down at anytime. And sometimes these sites are being abused, so they can get blocked.*

With that being said, below are multiple methods that can be used to accomplish your use case related to scraping content from the Yellow Pages.

### UPDATE 07-11-2022 16:47 GMT

I tried a different proxy validation method this morning.  It is slightly faster than the `proxy judge` method.  The issue with both these methods is error handling.  I have to catch all the errors below when validating a proxy IP address and passing a validated address to your function `fetch_resp`.

```
ConnectionResetError
requests.exceptions.ConnectTimeout
requests.exceptions.ProxyError
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError
requests.exceptions.HTTPError
requests.exceptions.Timeout 
requests.exceptions.TooManyRedirects
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError
urllib3.exceptions.ProxySchemeUnknown
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError
```

Occasionally a proxy fails when extracting from a page, which causes a delay. There is nothing you can do to prevent these failures.  The only thing you can do is catch the error and reprocess the request.

I was able to improve the extraction time by adding threading to function `get_content`.

```
Content Extraction Runtime: 0:00:03.475362
Total Runtime: 0:01:16.617862
```

The only way you can increase the speed of your code is to redesign it to query each page element at the same time.  If you don't this is a timing bottleneck.

Here is the code that I used to validate the proxy addresses.

```
def check_proxy(proxy):
    try:
        session = requests.Session()
        session.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.131 Safari/537.36'
        session.max_redirects = 300
        proxy = proxy.split('\n', 1)[0]
        # print('Checking ' + proxy)
        req = session.get("http://google.com", proxies={'http':'http://' + proxy}, timeout=30, allow_redirects=True)
        if req.status_code == 200:
            return proxy

    except requests.exceptions.ConnectTimeout as e:
        return None
    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as e:
        return None
    except ConnectionResetError as e:
        # print('Error,ConnectionReset!')
        return None
    except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as e:
        return None
    except requests.exceptions.Timeout as e:
        return None
    except ProxySchemeUnknown as e:
        return None
    except ProtocolError as e:
        return None
    except requests.exceptions.ChunkedEncodingError as e:
        return None
    except requests.exceptions.TooManyRedirects as e:
        return None
```

### UPDATE 07-10-2022 23:53 GMT

I did some more research into this question.  I have noted that the website https://www.sslproxies.org provides a list of 100 HTTPS.  Out of those less than 20% pass the `proxy judge` test.  Even after obtaining this 20% some will fail when being passed to your function `fetch_resp`.  They can fail for multiple reasons, which include ConnectTimeout, MaxRetryError, ProxyError, etc.  When this happens you can rerun the function with the same link (url), headers and a new proxy.  The best workaround for these errors is to use a commercial proxy service.

In my latest test I was able to obtain a list of potentially  functional proxies and extract all the content for all 25 pages related to your search.  Below is the timeDelta for this test:

```
Content Extraction Runtime: 0:00:34.176803
Total Runtime: 0:01:22.429338
```

I can speed this up if I use threading with the function `fetch_resp`.

Below is the current code that I'm using.  I need to improve the error handling, but it currently works.

```
import time
import random
import requests
from datetime import timedelta
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from proxy_checking import ProxyChecker
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter
from urllib3.util.retry import Retry
from urllib3.exceptions import MaxRetryError, ProxySchemeUnknown
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, as_completed

proxies_addresses = []
current_proxy = ''


def requests_retry_session(retries=5,
                           backoff_factor=0.5,
                           status_force_list=(500, 502, 503, 504),
                           session=None,
                           ):
    session = session or requests.Session()

    retry = Retry(
        total=retries,
        read=retries,
        connect=retries,
        backoff_factor=backoff_factor,
        status_forcelist=status_force_list,
    )
    adapter = HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retry)
    session.mount('http://', adapter)
    session.mount('https://', adapter)
    return session


def ssl_proxy_addresses():
    global proxies_addresses
    response = requests.get('https://www.sslproxies.org/')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")
    proxies = []
    table = soup.find('tbody')
    table_rows = table.find_all('tr')
    for row in table_rows:
        ip_address = row.find_all('td')[0]
        port_number = row.find_all('td')[1]
        proxies.append(f'{ip_address.text}:{port_number.text}')
    proxies_addresses = proxies
    return proxies


def proxy_verification(current_proxy_address):
    checker = ProxyChecker()
    proxy_judge = checker.check_proxy(current_proxy_address)
    proxy_status = bool([value for key, value in proxy_judge.items() if key == 'status' and value is True])
    if proxy_status is True:
        return current_proxy_address
    else:
        return None


def get_proxy_address():
    global proxies_addresses
    proxy_addresses = ssl_proxy_addresses()
    processes = []
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=40) as executor:
        for proxy_address in proxy_addresses:
            processes.append(executor.submit(proxy_verification, proxy_address))

    proxies = [task.result() for task in as_completed(processes) if task.result() is not None]
    proxies_addresses = proxies
    return proxies_addresses


def fetch_resp(link, http_headers, proxy_url):
    try:
        print(F'Current Proxy: {proxy_url}')

        response = requests_retry_session().get(link,
                                                headers=http_headers,
                                                allow_redirects=True,
                                                verify=True,
                                                proxies=proxy_url,
                                                timeout=(30, 45)
                                                )

        print("status code", response.status_code)
        if response.status_code == 200:
            return response
        else:
            current_proxy = proxies_addresses.pop(random.randrange(len(proxies_addresses)))
            fetch_resp(link, http_headers, current_proxy)

    except requests.exceptions.ConnectTimeout as e:
        print('Error,Timeout!')
        current_proxy = proxies_addresses.pop(random.randrange(len(proxies_addresses)))
        fetch_resp(link, http_headers, current_proxy)
        pass
    except requests.exceptions.ProxyError as e:
        print('ProxyError!')
        current_proxy = proxies_addresses.pop(random.randrange(len(proxies_addresses)))
        fetch_resp(link, http_headers, current_proxy)
        pass
    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as e:
        print('Connection Error')
        current_proxy = proxies_addresses.pop(random.randrange(len(proxies_addresses)))
        fetch_resp(link, http_headers, current_proxy)
        pass
    except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as e:
        print('HTTP ERROR!')
        current_proxy = proxies_addresses.pop(random.randrange(len(proxies_addresses)))
        fetch_resp(link, http_headers, current_proxy)
        pass
    except requests.exceptions.Timeout as e:
        print('Error! Connection Timeout!')
        current_proxy = proxies_addresses.pop(random.randrange(len(proxies_addresses)))
        fetch_resp(link, http_headers, current_proxy)
        pass
    except ProxySchemeUnknown as e:
        print('ERROR unknown Proxy Scheme!')
        current_proxy = proxies_addresses.pop(random.randrange(len(proxies_addresses)))
        fetch_resp(link, http_headers, current_proxy)
        pass
    except MaxRetryError as e:
        print('MaxRetryError')
        current_proxy = proxies_addresses.pop(random.randrange(len(proxies_addresses)))
        fetch_resp(link, http_headers, current_proxy)
        pass
    except requests.exceptions.TooManyRedirects as e:
        print('ERROR! Too many redirects!')
        current_proxy = proxies_addresses.pop(random.randrange(len(proxies_addresses)))
        fetch_resp(link, http_headers, current_proxy)
        pass


def get_content(http_headers, proxy_url):
    start_time = time.time()
    results = []
    pages = int(25)
    for page_number in range(1, pages):
        print(page_number)
        next_url = f"https://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=pizza&geo_location_terms=Los%20Angeles%2C%20CA" \
                   f"&page={page_number}"
        res = fetch_resp(next_url, http_headers, proxy_url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "lxml")
        info_sections = soup.find_all('li', {'class': 'business-card'})
        for info_section in info_sections:
            shop_name = info_section.find('h2', {'class': 'title business-name'})
            categories = ', '.join([i.text for i in info_section.find_all('a', {'class': 'category'})])
            results.append({shop_name.text, categories})
    end_time = time.time() - start_time
    print(f'Content Extraction Runtime: {timedelta(seconds=end_time)}')
    return results


start_time = time.time()
get_proxy_address()

if len(proxies_addresses) != 0:
    print(proxies_addresses)
    print('\n')
    current_proxy = proxies_addresses.pop(random.randrange(len(proxies_addresses)))
    print(current_proxy)
    print('\n')

    base_url = 'https://www.yellowpages.com{}'
    current_url = 'https://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=pizza&geo_location_terms=Los+Angeles%2C+CA'

    headers = {
        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 13_3_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/13.0.5 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1',
    }

    PROXIES = {
        'https': f"http://{current_proxy}"
    }

    results = get_content(headers, PROXIES)

end_time = time.time() - start_time
print(f'Total Runtime: {timedelta(seconds=end_time)}')
```

### **UPDATE 07-06-2022 11:02 GMT**

This seems to be your core question:

> **How can I quickly select a functional proxy from a list of proxies?**

First, all my previous code is able to validate that a proxy is working at a **given moment in time**.  Once validated I'm able to query and extract data from your **Yellow Pages** search for *pizza* in *Los Angeles*.

Using my previous method I'm able to query and extract data for all 24 pages related to your search in 0:00:45.367209 seconds.

Back to your question.

The website https://www.sslproxies.org provides a list of 100 HTTPS proxies.  There is zero guarantee that all 100 are currently operational.  One of the ways to identify the working ones is using a **Proxy Judge** service.

In my previous code I continually selected a random proxy from the list of 100 and passed this proxy to a **Proxy Judge** for validation.  Once a proxy is validated to be working it is used to query and extract data **Yellow Pages**.

The method above works, but I was wondering how many proxies out of the 100 pass the sniff test for the **Proxy Judge** service. I attempted to check using a basic `for loop`, which was deathly slow.  I decided to `concurrent.futures` to speed up the validation.

The code below takes about 1 minute to obtain a list of HTTPS proxies and validate them using a **Proxy Judge** service.

***This is the fastest way to obtain a list of free proxies that are functional at a specific moment in time.***

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from proxy_checking import ProxyChecker
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, as_completed

def ssl_proxy_addresses():
    response = requests.get('https://www.sslproxies.org/')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")
    proxies = []
    table = soup.find('tbody')
    table_rows = table.find_all('tr')
    for row in table_rows:
        ip_address = row.find_all('td')[0]
        port_number = row.find_all('td')[1]
        proxies.append(f'{ip_address.text}:{port_number.text}')
    return proxies


def proxy_verification(current_proxy_address):
    checker = ProxyChecker()
    proxy_judge = checker.check_proxy(current_proxy_address)
    proxy_status = bool([value for key, value in proxy_judge.items() if key == 'status' and value is True])
    if proxy_status is True:
        return current_proxy_address
    else:
        return None


def get_proxy_address():
    proxy_addresses = ssl_proxy_addresses()
    processes = []
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=20) as executor:
        for proxy_address in proxy_addresses:
            processes.append(executor.submit(proxy_verification, proxy_address))

    proxies = [task.result() for task in as_completed(processes) if task.result() is not None]
    print(len(proxies))
    13

    print(proxies)
    ['34.228.74.208:8080', '198.41.67.18:8080', '139.9.64.238:443', '216.238.72.163:59394', '64.189.24.250:3129', '62.193.108.133:1976', '210.212.227.68:3128', '47.241.165.133:443', '20.26.4.251:3128', '185.76.9.123:3128', '129.41.171.244:8000', '12.231.44.251:3128', '5.161.105.105:80']
```

### **UPDATE CODE 07-05-2022 17:07 GMT**

I added a snippet of code below to query the second page.  I did this to see if the proxy stayed the same, which it did.  You still need to add some error handling.

***In my testing I was able to query all 24 pages related to your search in 0:00:45.367209 seconds.  I don't consider this query and extraction speed slow by any means.***

Concerning performing a different search.  I would do the same method as below, but I would request a new proxy for this search, because free proxies do have limitations, such as life time and performance degradation.

```
import random
import logging
import requests
import traceback
from time import sleep
from random import randint
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from proxy_checking import ProxyChecker
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter
from urllib3.util.retry import Retry
from urllib3.exceptions import ProxySchemeUnknown
from http_request_randomizer.requests.proxy.ProxyObject import Protocol
from http_request_randomizer.requests.proxy.requestProxy import RequestProxy

current_proxy = ''


def requests_retry_session(retries=5,
                           backoff_factor=0.5,
                           status_force_list=(500, 502, 503, 504),
                           session=None,
                           ):
    session = session or requests.Session()

    retry = Retry(
        total=retries,
        read=retries,
        connect=retries,
        backoff_factor=backoff_factor,
        status_forcelist=status_force_list,
    )
    adapter = HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retry)
    session.mount('http://', adapter)
    session.mount('https://', adapter)
    return session


def random_ssl_proxy_address():
    try:
        # Obtain a list of HTTPS proxies
        # Suppress the console debugging output by setting the log level
        req_proxy = RequestProxy(log_level=logging.ERROR, protocol=Protocol.HTTPS)

        # Obtain a random single proxy from the list of proxy addresses
        random_proxy = random.sample(req_proxy.get_proxy_list(), 1)

        return random_proxy[0].get_address()
    except AttributeError as e:
        pass


def proxy_verification(current_proxy_address):
    checker = ProxyChecker()
    proxy_judge = checker.check_proxy(current_proxy_address)
    proxy_status = bool([value for key, value in proxy_judge.items() if key == 'status' and value is True])
    return proxy_status


def get_proxy_address():
    global current_proxy
    random_proxy_address = random_ssl_proxy_address()
    current_proxy = random_proxy_address
    proxy_status = proxy_verification(random_proxy_address)
    if proxy_status is True:
        return
    else:
        print('Looking for a valid proxy address.')

        # this sleep timer is helping with some timeout issues
        # that were happening when querying
        sleep(randint(5, 10))

        get_proxy_address()


def fetch_resp(link, http_headers, proxy_url):
    try:
        response = requests_retry_session().get(link,
                                                headers=http_headers,
                                                allow_redirects=True,
                                                verify=True,
                                                proxies=proxy_url,
                                                timeout=(30, 45)
                                                )
        print(F'Current Proxy: {proxy_url}')
        print("status code", response.status_code)
        return response
    except requests.exceptions.ConnectTimeout as e:
        print('Error,Timeout!')
        print(''.join(traceback.format_tb(e.__traceback__)))
    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as e:
        print('Connection Error')
        print(''.join(traceback.format_tb(e.__traceback__)))
    except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as e:
        print('HTTP ERROR!')
        print(''.join(traceback.format_tb(e.__traceback__)))
    except requests.exceptions.Timeout as e:
        print('Error! Connection Timeout!')
        print(''.join(traceback.format_tb(e.__traceback__)))
    except ProxySchemeUnknown as e:
        print('ERROR unknown Proxy Scheme!')
        print(''.join(traceback.format_tb(e.__traceback__)))
    except requests.exceptions.TooManyRedirects as e:
        print('ERROR! Too many redirects!')
        print(''.join(traceback.format_tb(e.__traceback__)))
       


def get_next_page(raw_soup, http_headers, proxy_urls):
    next_page_element = raw_soup.find('a', {'class': 'paginator-next arrow-next'})
    next_url = f"https://www.yellowpages.com{next_page_element['href']}"
    sub_response = fetch_resp(next_url, http_headers, proxy_urls)
    new_soup = BeautifulSoup(sub_response.text, "lxml")
    return new_soup


def get_content(link, http_headers, proxy_urls):
    res = fetch_resp(link, http_headers, proxy_urls)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "lxml")
    info_sections = soup.find_all('li', {'class': 'business-card'})
    for info_section in info_sections:
        shop_name = info_section.find('h2', {'class': 'title business-name'})
         print(shop_name.text)
            categories = ', '.join([i.text for i in info_section.find_all('a', {'class': 'category'})])
            print(categories)
            business_website = info_section.find('a', {'class': 'website listing-cta action'})
            if business_website is not None:
                print(business_website['href'])
            elif business_website is None:
                print('no website')

    # get page 2
    if soup.find('a', {'class': 'paginator-next arrow-next'}) is not None:
        soup_next_page = get_next_page(soup, http_headers, proxy_urls)
        info_sections = soup_next_page.find_all('li', {'class': 'business-card'})
        for info_section in info_sections:
            shop_name = info_section.find('h2', {'class': 'title business-name'})
             print(shop_name.text)
            categories = ', '.join([i.text for i in info_section.find_all('a', {'class': 'category'})])
            print(categories)
            business_website = info_section.find('a', {'class': 'website listing-cta action'})
            if business_website is not None:
                print(business_website['href'])
            elif business_website is None:
                print('no website')


get_proxy_address()
if len(current_proxy) != 0:
    print(current_proxy)

    base_url = 'https://www.yellowpages.com{}'
    current_url = 'https://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=pizza&geo_location_terms=Los+Angeles%2C+CA'

    headers = {
        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 13_3_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/13.0.5 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1',
    }

    PROXIES = {
        'https': f"http://{current_proxy}"
    }

    get_content(current_url, headers, PROXIES)
```

truncated output

```
Current Proxy: {'https': 'http://157.185.161.123:59394'}
status code 200
1.Casa Bianca Pizza Pie
2.Palermo Italian Restaurant
... truncated


Current Proxy: {'https': 'http://157.185.161.123:59394'}
status code 200
31.Johnnie's New York Pizzeria
32.Amalfi Restaurant and Bar
... truncated
```

### **UPDATE CODE 07-05-2022 14:07 GMT**

I reworked my code posted on 07-01-2022 to output these data elements, business name, business categories and business website.

```
1.Casa Bianca Pizza Pie
Pizza, Italian Restaurants, Restaurants
http://www.casabiancapizza.com

2.Palermo Italian Restaurant
Pizza, Restaurants, Italian Restaurants
no website

... truncated
```

### **UPDATE CODE 07-01-2022**

I noted that when using the free proxies errors were being thrown.  I added the `requests_retry_session` function to handle this.  I didn't rework all your code, but I did make sure that I could query the site and produce results using a free proxy. You should be able to work my code into yours.

```
import random
import logging
import requests
from time import sleep
from random import randint
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from proxy_checking import ProxyChecker
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter
from requests.packages.urllib3.util.retry import Retry
from http_request_randomizer.requests.proxy.ProxyObject import Protocol
from http_request_randomizer.requests.proxy.requestProxy import RequestProxy

current_proxy = ''

def requests_retry_session(retries=5,
                            backoff_factor=0.5,
                            status_force_list=(500, 502, 504),
                            session=None,
                            ):
    session = session or requests.Session()

    retry = Retry(
        total=retries,
        read=retries,
        connect=retries,
        backoff_factor=backoff_factor,
        status_forcelist=status_force_list,
    )
    adapter = HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retry)
    session.mount('http://', adapter)
    session.mount('https://', adapter)
    return session


def random_ssl_proxy_address():
    try:
        # Obtain a list of HTTPS proxies
        # Suppress the console debugging output by setting the log level
        req_proxy = RequestProxy(log_level=logging.ERROR, protocol=Protocol.HTTPS)

        # Obtain a random single proxy from the list of proxy addresses
        random_proxy = random.sample(req_proxy.get_proxy_list(), 1)

        return random_proxy[0].get_address()
    except AttributeError as e:
        pass


def proxy_verification(current_proxy_address):
    checker = ProxyChecker()
    proxy_judge = checker.check_proxy(current_proxy_address)
    proxy_status = bool([value for key, value in proxy_judge.items() if key == 'status' and value is True])
    return proxy_status


def get_proxy_address():
    global current_proxy
    random_proxy_address = random_ssl_proxy_address()
    current_proxy = random_proxy_address
    proxy_status = proxy_verification(random_proxy_address)
    if proxy_status is True:
        return
    else:
        print('Looking for a valid proxy address.')

        # this sleep timer is helping with some timeout issues
        # that were happening when querying
        sleep(randint(5, 10))

        get_proxy_address()


def fetch_resp(link, http_headers, proxy_url):

    response = requests_retry_session().get(link,
                                            headers=http_headers,
                                            allow_redirects=True,
                                            verify=True,
                                            proxies=proxy_url,
                                            timeout=(30, 45)
                                                  )
    print("status code", response.status_code)
    return response


def get_content(link, headers, proxy_urls):
    res = fetch_resp(link, headers, proxy_urls)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "lxml")
    info_sections = soup.find_all('li', {'class': 'business-card'})
    for info_section in info_sections:
        shop_name = info_section.find('h2', {'class': 'title business-name'})
        print(shop_name.text)
        categories = ', '.join([i.text for i in info_section.find_all('a', {'class': 'category'})])
        print(categories)
        business_website = info_section.find('a', {'class': 'website listing-cta action'})
        if business_website is not None:
            print(business_website['href'])
        elif business_website is None:
            print('no website')

get_proxy_address()
if len(current_proxy) != 0:
    print(current_proxy)

    base_url = 'https://www.yellowpages.com{}'
    current_url = 'https://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=pizza&geo_location_terms=Los+Angeles%2C+CA'

    headers = {
        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 13_3_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/13.0.5 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1',
    }

    PROXIES = {
        'https': f"http://{current_proxy}"
    }

    get_content(current_url, headers, PROXIES)
```

### **PREVIOUS ANSWERS**

**06-30-2022:**

During some testing I found a bug, so I updated my code to handle the bug.

**06-28-2022:**

You could use a proxy judge, which is used for testing the performance and the anonymity status of a proxy server.

The code below is from one of my [previous answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68673903/not-able-to-set-proxy-in-selenium-python/68702682#68702682).

```
import random
import logging
from time import sleep
from random import randint
from proxy_checking import ProxyChecker
from http_request_randomizer.requests.proxy.ProxyObject import Protocol
from http_request_randomizer.requests.proxy.requestProxy import RequestProxy


current_proxy = ''


def random_ssl_proxy_address():
    try:
        # Obtain a list of HTTPS proxies
        # Suppress the console debugging output by setting the log level
        req_proxy = RequestProxy(log_level=logging.ERROR, protocol=Protocol.HTTPS)

        # Obtain a random single proxy from the list of proxy addresses
        random_proxy = random.sample(req_proxy.get_proxy_list(), 1)

        return random_proxy[0].get_address()
    except AttributeError as e:
        pass


def proxy_verification(current_proxy_address):
    checker = ProxyChecker()
    proxy_judge = checker.check_proxy(current_proxy_address)
    proxy_status = bool([value for key, value in proxy_judge.items() if key == 'status' and value is True])
    return proxy_status


def get_proxy_address():
    global current_proxy
    random_proxy_address = random_ssl_proxy_address()
    current_proxy = random_proxy_address
    proxy_status = proxy_verification(random_proxy_address)
    if proxy_status is True:
        return
    else:
        print('Looking for a valid proxy address.')

        # this sleep timer is helping with some timeout issues
        # that were happening when querying
        sleep(randint(5, 10))

        get_proxy_address()


get_proxy_address()
if len(current_proxy) != 0:
    print(f'Valid proxy address: {current_proxy}')
    # output
    Valid proxy address: 157.100.12.138:999
```

I noted today that the Python package [HTTP_Request_Randomizer](https://github.com/pgaref/HTTP_Request_Randomizer) has a couple of `Beautiful Soup` path problems that need to be modified, because they currently don't work in version 1.3.2 of HTTP_Request_Randomizer.

You need to modified line 27 in `FreeProxyParser.py` to this:

```
table = soup.find("table", attrs={"class": "table table-striped table-bordered"})
```

You need to modified line 27 in `SslProxyParser.py` to this:

```
table = soup.find("table", attrs={"class": "table table-striped table-bordered"})
```

I found another bug that needs to be fixed.  This one is in the `proxy_checking.py` I had to add the line `if url != None:`

```
    def get_info(self, url=None, proxy=None):
        info = {}
        proxy_type = []
        judges = ['http://proxyjudge.us/azenv.php', 'http://azenv.net/', 'http://httpheader.net/azenv.php', 'http://mojeip.net.pl/asdfa/azenv.php']
        if url != None:
            try:
                response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, timeout=5)
                return response
            except:
                pass
        elif proxy != None:
```

Comment: As we are dealing with `https` site, so the proxy should be used here in this format `'https': f"http://{current_proxy}"`, right?

Comment: Yes. I was doing some troubling shooting, because of was getting this **Your proxy appears to only use HTTP and not HTTPS**

Comment: I fixed that line in the code.  And it works without errors.

Comment: The script that I've used in my post works flawlessly. The only problem with it is that it works slowly. However, when I run you suggested script, I could notice that it also performs very slowly. Moreover, it sometimes produces non working proxy which makes the program crash. We are using free proxies within the script and free proxies are short lived, so by the time we test the validity of a proxy using a different url, it becomes dead and that is the reason I used proxies directly within the script.

Comment: As I stated you need to add error handling to handle underlying proxy issues associated with a "free proxy."

Comment: I'm also using free proxies, but I'm try to validate that the are working with the proxy judges.  I rarely have any issues with this method.

Comment: Concerning speed. I'm unsure what "slow" means to you. I was able to scrape all 24 pages in 0:00:45.367209. Of course this speed is highly dependent on the proxy being used.