# How to use proxies with Selenium Python?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, proxy, selenium-chromedriver

I need to use a proxy for my program and have problems with implementing it in this code.

Can someone help me?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from varNames import *
from disc import *
from functions import *
from seleniumwire import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
driver.get("url")

# Logging in

sleep(10)
login(email_input, password_input, driver)

# Close the WebDriver after you are done

driver.quit()
```

Comment: What does "*have problems with implementing*" mean? **Please [edit] to describe what problems are you _exactly_ having or encountering.** Have you tried checking related posts, like this [Running Selenium Webdriver with a proxy in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17082425/2745495)? Are you getting error messages when you tried adding a proxy? Then please post that as part of your question. Are you expecting a specific behavior? Then please describe the expected behavior vs the actual behavior you are getting.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Not able to set proxy in selenium Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68673903/not-able-to-set-proxy-in-selenium-python)